# Duplicated records for a column

Tags: mysql, distinct, duplicate-data

I'm trying to get duplicated values in `col1` for a certain `col2` value.

Suppose that I have that table:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | col1       | col2     |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 5          | 2        |
|  2 | 5          | 1        |
|  3 | 8          | 4        |
|  4 | 8          | 1        |
|  5 | 8          | 3        |
|  6 | 5          | 2        |
|  7 | 2          | 3        |
|  8 | 1          | 4        |
|  9 | 2          | 2        |
| 10 | 5          | 2        |
| 11 | 5          | 3        |
| 12 | 3          | 1        |
+----+------------+----------+
```

My query should return these rows when `col2 = 1`:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | col1       | col2     |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 5          | 2        |
|  6 | 5          | 2        |
| 10 | 5          | 2        |
| 11 | 5          | 3        |
|  3 | 8          | 4        |
|  5 | 8          | 3        |
+----+------------+----------+
```

I have tried this query and it works pretty well for me:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT b.* 
FROM table a,table b 
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = 1 AND b.col2 != 1
```

As you can see, `DISTINCT` is killing for a huge table with 100k records and it's daily growing.

I need all values so I can't use `GROUP BY` clause.

Looking for a better and faster solution. If its better, I can change the whole structure.

Comment: Did you maybe mean to write `WHERE a.col1 = b.col1` (with a `1` at the end), rather than `WHERE a.col1 = b.col2` like you have now? Because your current query doesn't match your sample results.

Comment: Edit your answer. When you say col2 = 1 you want to say != 1

Comment: My brain stoped working. I corrected the query.

Comment: @danihp: No, that is correct, he has `SELECT b.*`

Comment: @tuze: WHat indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: @ypercube both col1 and col2 have indexes.

Comment: Adding another compound index on `(col2, col1)` would help this, as @danihp points out.

Comment: @ypercube, at this point question is ambigus because query says 'b.col2 != 1'. May be correct and not.

Comment: @danihp It's correct because It's fetching results from b only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table AS a 
WHERE col2 <> 1
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table b
        WHERE b.col1 = a.col1 
          AND b.col2 = 1
      )
```

Comment: Don't forget to create an index on col2, col1

Comment: I don't remember if MySQL optimize it or not, but you can replace `SELECT *` by `SELECT NULL` (or any other constant) in the subquery.